# SSIS OnError Event Handler finishes but does not continue the tasks within the For Loop Container

Tags: ssis

I have a package that updates a large set of tables when executed.
On occasions the package will fail due to a mismatch in column numbers between the old version of the tables and the new updated version of the table until all tables in the view are updated.

The parent package will select all the tables required in a view and then run a For Loop Container going through each table and updating said table. The child package just runs a series of tasks that updates the local version of the table then reruns itself with a new table.

I have created an OnError Event Handler to deal with the scenario where the child package will fail when applying the new updated rows to the old table. The Event handler rectifies the task issue then reruns the whole child package again for that specific table successfully as it should. However, when it finishes the tasks for that specific table, the package immediately ends and does not continue running the for loop and going on to the next table.

How can I resolve this within the package? I want the package to keep running despite the failure but I don't know how to get the package to continue the for loop after the Even Handler.

Example of package flow;

> T.Customers runs successfully
> T.Sales fails during child package
> OnError handler kicks in
> T.Sales now runs successfully
> Package now ends with a failure (Completes the T.Sales table but still shows a package failure)
> T.Returns has not been ran as the
> package ended after the OnError event finishes the previous table.

Comment: There is a property for each item in the data flow saying fail package on failure.  I think you have to set that to false.  The one you want to fail but keep going, you have to set that to false.

Comment: Have a look at the `MaximumErrorCount` property for SSIS containers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/integration-services-containers?view=sql-server-ver16